# JSF modular web application

Tags: jsf, content-management-system, module, modular

talking about a modular web application like a Content Management System, where you can upload and install separated modules, I would like to know what is the best way to develop separeted modules (like News, rss Reader, Forum, etc...) using JSF, that could be put in packages and uploaded into the modular web application.

Thank you!
F.

Comment: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/~lexi/Modular+JSF++Applications

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw the post but is not enough clear for my experience... I understand it but I need more information.. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution...

Simply use composite components... I was thinking that CC were useful to build little custom components only, but not to build entire sections of the view... this is not true. This article in IBM web site shows that it is possible to use CC also to build big parts of the view:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html

Good and easy! :)